# Add reference to a Servicestack simpleservice in VS 2013 fails

Tags: soap, visual-studio-2013, wsdl, servicestack

I have an interesting problem. If i have a return object on my servicestack method and wnat to use SOAP, VS2013 can generate a proxy with add service reference. BUT if i have a return type string on the method it fails with "Custom tool warning: Cannot import wsdl:portType" and 3 more errors.

The only difference between the methods are:

```
    [TerminalAuth]
    public CloseOrderResponse Any(CloseOrder dto)
    {

        var resp = new CloseOrderResponse() {Data = "bla"};
        return resp;

    }
    [TerminalAuth]
    public string Any(CloseOrder2 dto)
    {
        return "bla";
    }
```

If i comment/hide the second method it generates the reference.cs just fine, but with the second (or only the second) it fails. The result is that the reference.cs has only the comment header and no code

Any ideas anyone?

/Erik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you read the [ServiceStack SOAP Limitations](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/SOAP-support#soap-limitations):

> SOAP expects that each request always returns the same response DTO.
>   So you need to follow the response DTO naming convention, otherwise
>   ServiceStack won't be able to generate the WSDLs and the SOAP endpoint
>   won't work.

#### DTO Naming Conventions

Naming convention: `{Request DTO Name}` + Response

Example: Request DTO: `DeleteCustomer` -> Response DTO: `DeleteCustomerResponse`

You can hide incompatible types from being generated in the WSDL with the `[Exclude]` attribute, e.g:

```
[Exclude(Feature.Soap)]
public class CloseOrder2 
{
}
```

Comment: Hi

Thanks for answering.

So what you are saying is that I can't have a method consumed by a soap call if I only have return object string? What I mean is that it only returns a string of text, not an object.

Because I need them to be consumed by soap.

Comment: @user3378248 It needs to return a Typed DTO with the naming convention specified above. To return a string you can wrap it in a Response DTO e.g `return new CloseOrder2Response { Result="bla" }`. Otherwise to return a raw string exclude it from SOAP and call it from a normal HTTP Client.